# JFace Tabs inside ContainerSelectionDialog in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, dialog, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am using an `ContainerSelectionDialog` inside my Eclipse RCP application. I now would like to add tabs to the dialog, with some additional stuff inside.

This is how my `ContainerSelectionDialog` looks like:

```
// ...
ContainerSelectionDialog dialog = new ContainerSelectionDialog(
        Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), c, true,
        "Please select target folder");
int open = dialog.open();
if (!(open == org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.OK))
    return null;
Object[] result = dialog.getResult();

IPath path = (IPath) result[0];
targetFolder = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()
        .findMember(path);
containerPath = targetFolder.getLocation().toPortableString();
// ...
```

How can I add tabs to this dialog?

Comment: I think the best you can do with this dialog is add additional controls **below** the tree.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is add controls below the selection tree. Even this is made difficult by a bug in `ContainerSelectionDialog`. This code shows how to do this and work around the bug:

```
public class MyContainerSelectionDialog extends ContainerSelectionDialog
{
  public MyContainerSelectionDialog(final Shell parentShell, final IContainer initialRoot, final boolean allowNewContainerName, final String message)
  {
    super(parentShell, initialRoot, allowNewContainerName, message);
  }

  @Override
  protected Control createDialogArea(final Composite parent)
  {
    Composite body = (Composite)super.createDialogArea(parent);

    // Bug in ContainerSelectionDialog is returning null for the body!

    if (body == null)
     {
       // body is the last control added to the parent

       final Control [] children = parent.getChildren();

       if (children[children.length - 1] instanceof Composite)
         body = (Composite)children[children.length - 1];
     }

    // TODO add your controls here, this example just adds a Label

    final Label label = new Label(body, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText("My label");

    return body;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the `ContainerSelectionDialog` as a child element to a kind of tabbed dialog, so that the `ContainerSelectionDialog` is the content of one of many tabs? I can't find an element, which allows me to define a tabbed dialog...

Comment: Not really, it is designed to be a stand-alone dialog.

Comment: Oh, I see. What could be a possibility to implement such a tabbed dialog with a kind of `ContainerSelectionDialog` as the content of one of the tabs?

Comment: Most of the work in this dialog is done in the `ContainerSelectionGroup` class which could be used in a tab, **but** this is an **internal** class and using it in your code would break the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html). This class is fairly small so you could write you own version of it.